# Shrink a div according to its priority to zero width with css

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to shrink a div according to its priority to zero width with css?

I will show my use case for this. First code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
  padding: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.second {
  background-color: green;
  flex-shrink: 200000;
}

.third {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-shrink: 300000;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="first">
    firstfirstfirstfirstfirstfirstfirstfirstfirstfirstfirstfirstfirst
      </div>
      <div class="second">
    secondsecondsecondsecondsecondsecondsecondsecondsecondsecondsecondsecondsecond
      </div>
      <div class="third">
    thirdthirdthirdthirdthirdthirdthirdthirdthirdthirdthirdthird
      </div>
    </div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oobarbazanoo/xr4syf53/2/)

Now I will explain what I want to happen.

There are three columns. From left to right: first, second and third column (priority wise the first column is the most important, then the second and then the third; by priority I mean what column should try to show its full content first, the most priortized column should try to show its full content first). All the columns can take only a single line.

Now I want the following: first column should take all the space it requires and if it requires more space than available (overflows the line), then I would like to hide what overflows and add ellipsis to the text in it. After that if there is no more space in the line I would like not to see the second and third rows at all. If there is more space present, then I would like to show the second column and in case it does not fit I would like the ellipses to its text being added on overflow. Then the remaining space (if present) should be taken by the thrid column and ellipsis should be added on overflow for its text, in case there is no remaining space, then the third column should not be visible at all.

Hope I explained well my intentions.

**UPDATE**

I was able to achieve the desired effect with the help of the `flex-shrink`. The current issues are: the `1`, `200000` and `300000` values look like a technical debt to me. Also, as you can see from the result of running the code the second and the third columns do not shrink to 0 and it is still possible to see them:

[image]

Comment: It wont shrink to 0 because it has a padding of 2px

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes, in my use case I have the padding as well. So, I need the padding to be present, but to disappear when shrinked. I believe it might be impossible to achieve with the pure html+css bundle (the js might be necessary, but I do not consider it in this question).

Comment: Check out this answer if you're still interested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67858285