# How to have one item shrink fully before another starts to shrink?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a margin that disappears as the viewport becomes smaller, while the main content remains the same size as long as possible. This margin is supposed to have a maximum size, so using `auto` is out of the question.

In other terms, my question is how to control the shrink priority of different items on the website.

The Flexbox model allows to set the *ratio* of shrinkage, but not the order of it.

Which options, not using Javascript, do I have to achieve this?

<sub>Note: I'm answering my own question here but I'm also looking for better answers.</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### `flex-shrink`/`flex-grow`

One way is to have one flexbox item `flex-shrink`, and to have the other grow to the size it should have with `flex-grow`. This way, the latter item will 'shrink' (decrease its growth) first.

More than two levels can be achieved by nesting this construction.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.first-to-shrink {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0px;
  min-width: 0px;
  background: coral;
}

.second-to-shrink {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 0;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="first-to-shrink flex-container">
    <div class="first-to-shrink">
      This is going to shrink first!
    </div>
    <div class="second-to-shrink">
      And then this one is going to shrink!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-to-shrink flex-container">
    <div class="first-to-shrink">
      This one is going next!
    </div>
    <div class="second-to-shrink">
      This is the last one to disappear!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Size Calculation

Another way is to calculate the size for each item as the difference of the viewport and the size of all other items that should shrink after it (this requires knowing the size of each of them), as follows:

```css
.shrinkable {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 100px;
}

#first-to-shrink {
  height: calc(100vh - 300px);
  background: coral;
}

#second-to-shrink {
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

#third-to-shrink {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  background: coral;
}

#fourth-to-shrink {
  height: 100vh;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="first-to-shrink" class="shrinkable">
  This is going to shrink first!
</div>
<div id="second-to-shrink" class="shrinkable">
  And then this one is going to shrink!
</div>
<div id="third-to-shrink" class="shrinkable">
  This one is going next!
</div>
<div id="fourth-to-shrink" class="shrinkable">
  This is the last one to disappear!
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to rely on having some idea of the width of the third and fourth divs, can this be assumed (it's not stated in the question).

Comment: Great point. After some more reading up on the flexbox model and experimentation I managed to make it not rely on any hardcoded sizes.

Comment: Is it known that the container is either the width of the viewport (in the case of flex along the row) or the height of the viewport (as in your second case) - this is also info. that is not in the question :)- and if you know that you can use media queries.

Comment: The point of vertical vs horizontal was to minimize the amount of non-essential code in the snippets, I believe both can be adjusted for the other case with some additional rules.
What do you mean by using media queries? AIUI they provide discrete steps only, meaning that items will not continuously shrink and grow accordingly but rather appear and disappear (except for using an ungodly number of queries to approximate continuity - hardly a real option).

Comment: You want the second element to change to being able to shrink to 0 when the container gets too small, hence my question about whether the container in fact spans (or indeed is proportional to) the width or height of the viewport.

Comment: In my case the container was horizontal, but I still do not see the relevance - as the runnable snippets illustrate the items are capable of shrinking to 0 width in either case.

Comment: @hyperfekt I've tried the method using flex-shrink above and while it works great (very thankful for it too), I'm definitely confused by its behavior because it seems opposite of how I'd been trying to use flex values. The first-to-shrink has a smaller flex-shrink number than the second-to shrink, and I thought a higher number would result in a greater percentage of shrinkage? Is flex-basis the key here? This also confused me, as I thought the flex-basis is the initial value, and it's not starting at 0px wide?

Comment: It technically is starting at 0px wide, and then the flexbox algorithm (as instructed by the property) grows it to take up all remaining space. So when in turn there is less space available it will not grow as much, in effect shrinking together with the container. The key is to make a distinction between the flexbox algorithm (which is in effect run anew for every new situation) and the observed behavior (which is in reference to the previous situation).